# Jenkins Slaves Randomly Disconnect from the Master

Tags: java, networking, jenkins, continuous-integration, virtual-machine

I'm currently setting up a vm cluster to run Jenkins for use with a large project,
I have jenkins set up, all the VM's are running Windows 7 64-bit with plenty of ram, disk space and the slave agents deployed (running as windows service).I keep getting the following error after a few minutes.

```
Connection was broken

java.nio.channels.AsynchronousCloseException
at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.end(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(Unknown Source)
at hudson.remoting.SocketChannelStream$1.read(SocketChannelStream.java:33)
at sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.InputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at hudson.remoting.FlightRecorderInputStream.read(FlightRecorderInputStream.java:82)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.peek(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peek(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
at hudson.remoting.Command.readFrom(Command.java:92)
at hudson.remoting.ClassicCommandTransport.read(ClassicCommandTransport.java:70)
at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:48)
```

The slaves disconnect for 30 seconds to 2 minutes and then reconnect,
the response time also varies wildly between 400ms and 5 seconds.

The cluster is on its own switch and a ping from any machine returns a < 1ms time.

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a *lot* of bugs with the new NIO stuff in the Jenkins slave. We are experiencing similar serious instability issues up until the latest release at this time of writing.
For example:
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-22758

This posts deserves an update (August 2017): we are running 2.46 now and the slaves are a lot more stable.

Comment: I have downgraded to the LTS release. Currently running 1.565.2 and its stable, upgraded the switch and assigned each slave a static IP in the same subnet, its holding firm for now.

Comment: @SonicWind, recommendation: if you like reasonable stability, always run the LTS release.

Comment: @SonicWind which version were you downgrading from ?

Comment: @alfasin Downgraded from 1.594